# Remove unwanted characters from a huge file

Tags: c#

EDIT : Here's my current code (21233664 chars)

```
  string str = myInput.Text;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '_' || c==' ')
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        output.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Let's say I have a huge text file which contains special characters and normal expressions with underscores.

Here are a few examples of the **strings** that I'm looking for :

- super_test
- test
- another_super_test

As you can see, only lower case letters are allowed with underscores.
Now, if I have those strings in a text file that looks like this :

```
>  §> ˜;@  ®>  l? super_test D>ÿÿÿÿ “G? tI> €[> €? È
```

The problem I'm facing is that some lonely letters are still saved. In the example given above, the output would be :

```
l super_test t
```

To get ridden of those chars, I must go through the whole file again but here's my question : **how can I know whether a letter is lonely or not**?

I'm not sure I understand the possibilities with regex, so if anyone can give me a hint I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I think it's pretty safe to say that a letter is lonely when it is crying :-)

Comment: How "lonely" are we talking? You can add a minimum length requirement to your Regex.

Comment: How big is "huge"? How do you do the filtering you show?

Comment: "The problem I'm facing is that some lonely letters are still saved" -- Can you show us your current code that is doing the "saving"? It seems easier to fix your original code than to do a second iteration through the whole file. Otherwise, *my* definition of "a lonely letter" is if the character just in front and just behind it is whitespace.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. To identify single character you can use the following regex code `var matches = Regex.Matches(@"l super_test t", @"\b\w\b")`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers. I've updated the main post.

Comment: Can you guarantee that spaces will occur occasionally? If so, you could read a few characters into a string/stringbuilder until you reach a space, and if there is more than one character then process that data. Write to the new file. Repeat until the end of the file.

Answer (score 6):

You clearly need a regular expression. A simple one would be `[a-z_]{2,}`, which takes all strings of lowercase a to z letters and underscore that are at least 2 characters long.

Just be careful when you are parsing the big file. Being huge, I imagine you use some sort of buffers. You need to make sure you don't get half of a word in one buffer and the other in the next.

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat the space just like the other acceptable characters. In addition to being acceptable, the space also serves as a delimiter for your lonesome characters. (This might be a problem with the proposed regular expressions as well; I couldn't say for sure.) Anyway, this does what (I think) you want:

```
string str = ">  §> ˜;@  ®>  l? super_test D>ÿÿÿÿ “G? tI> €[> €? È";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char? firstLetterOfWord = null;
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '_')
    {
        int length = sb.Length;
        if (firstLetterOfWord != null)
        {
            // c is the second character of a word
            sb.Append(firstLetterOfWord);
            sb.Append(c);
            firstLetterOfWord = null;
        }
        else if (length == 0 || sb[length - 1] == ' ')
        {
            // c is the first character of a word; save for next iteration
            firstLetterOfWord = c;
        }
        else
        {
            // c is part of a word; we're not first, and prev != space
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    else if (c == ' ')
    {
        // If you want to eliminate multiple spaces in a row,
        // this is the place to do so
        sb.Append(' ');
        firstLetterOfWord = null;
    }
    else
    {
        firstLetterOfWord = null;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

It works with singletons and full words at both start and end of string.

If your input contains something like `one@two`, the output will run together (`onetwo` with no intervening space). Assuming that's not what you want, and also assuming that you have no need for multiple spaces in a row:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool previousWasSpace = true;
char? firstLetterOfWord = null;
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '_')
    {
        if (firstLetterOfWord != null)
        {
            sb.Append(firstLetterOfWord).Append(c);
            firstLetterOfWord = null;
            previousWasSpace = false;
        }
        else if (previousWasSpace)
        {
            firstLetterOfWord = c;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        firstLetterOfWord = null;
        if (!previousWasSpace)
        {
            sb.Append(' ');
            previousWasSpace = true;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```